# WPF - Categorized ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

**Data Types**

My MainWindow has a property called `Project project` which has a property `ObservableCollection<Drawable> Drawables`

```
public class Drawable {
    public enum DrawableType { Top, Head, Feet };

    public bool IsMale {get; set;}
    public bool IsFemale {get; set;}
    public DrawableType DrawableType {get; set;}

    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
}
```

For all Data types and properties I properly implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

**Current situation**

The ObservableCollection is displayed in a ListView but as it contains up to about 500 items it is hard to use the application. I would like to display the items in a TreeView-like structure categorized by the gender (IsMale, IsFemale) and the DrawableType like this:

- Male

  - Top (Drawables are display here if IsMale=true and DrawableType=DrawableType.Top)

    - Drawable 1
    - Drawable 2
    - Drawable 3
  - Head
  - Feet
- Female

  - Top (Drawables are display here if IsFemale=true and DrawableType=DrawableType.Top)

    - Drawable 2
  - Head
  - Feet

In this example Drawable 2 has IsFemale=true, the others have false.

**My problem**

During research I found that ListView actually supports grouping but I don't think this is what I want as a single instance of Drawable can be a children of up to two nodes (as with Drawable 2 belongs both to Male->Top and Female->Top)

**What I have tried**

I tried using a TreeView which provides all the visuals I need for this task but I can not get it to categorize the Drawable instances. I tried subscribing to the PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged events to create an ObservableCollection in order to create a structure that I can directly bind the TreeView to:

```
public class DrawableListEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public enum Sex {Male, Female}

    public Drawable Drawable;
    public DrawableType DrawableType = DrawableType.None;
    public Sex Sex = Sex.None;

    public string Label {
        get {
            if(Drawable != null) { return Drawable.DisplayName; }
            if(DrawableType != null) { return DrawableType.ToString(); }
            return Sex.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DrawableListEntry> Children {get; set;}
}
```

**My Question**

Is it possible to directly bind to the ObservableCollection and let a TreeView do the categorization automatically?

Please keep in mind, that I'm currently not adhering to any patterns like MVVM but I try to keep my business logic apart from the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During research I found that ListView actually supports grouping but I don't think this is what I want as a single instance of Drawable can be a children of up to two nodes (as with Drawable 2 belongs both to Male->Top and Female->Top)

Create a `DrawableViewModel` class with `Gender`, `DrawableType` and `DisplayName` properties and then add an instance of this class for each leaf entry that you want to display in the grouped `ListView`.

In this particular example you will then end up with a source collection of four items; Drawable 1, Drawable 2, Drawable 3 and another Drawable 2 (with the `Gender` property set to `Female` unlike the first one).

In other words, you should use the MVVM design pattern to basically transform your data model into something that works with the `ListView` control in the view.